# in app purchase with new version of the app

Tags: ios4, in-app-purchase

I have updated the current version of one of my application on app store so that it supports in-app purchase, it's been more than couple of hours and there is no in-app purchase visible on the appstore yet though on itunesconnect it says that the in-app purchase is ready for sell along with the new version of the app.

Can anyone tell me what might be wrong with my application?

Regards,

Ankur

Answer (score 0):

Did you check "Clear for Sale" for the InAppPurchase?